# Segmentation Fault : error code 11

Tags: c

The programe generates Segmentation fault: 11, on Yostemite

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (){

unsigned long long int inputNumber[99]={0};
int i = 0;

unsigned long long int input= 0;
scanf("%llu", &input);


while( input != EOF ){
        inputNumber[i] = input;
```

/** while debugging with gdb it gives : 
Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error. 
on above line. 
*/
            i++;
    };

```
for( ; i > 0; i--){
    printf("%.4f\n", sqrt(inputNumber[i]));
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great.  So did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.

Comment: `while( input != EOF )` infinite loop.

Comment: Might want to take a look at the `scanf` documentation for what it returns.

Comment: `input` will only be equal to `EOF` if the user enters the value representing `EOF` (`-1`). I recommend you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @ouah, I am passing it ^D as the last argument.

Comment: Move scanf inside the loop?

Comment: *What* "last" argument? You only have *one* `scanf` call, followed by a (possibly infinite) loop where you don't read any more input from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scanf call is not in the loop, so this runs forever and then overruns the array buffer:

```
while( input != EOF ){
        inputNumber[i] = input;
        i++;
};
```

Change to:

```
while( input != EOF ){
        inputNumber[i] = input;
        i++;
       scanf("%llu", &input);
};
```

Comment: In that case how the first digit will be scaned ? it will be '0' alway.

Answer (score 1):

As ouah mentioned in the comments, you have an infinite loop. `Input` is never being consumed-- it's simple a value that's being copied into every element of `inputNumber`. As the value of input remains constant over time, it will never equal EOF and the loop will never end (unless the user simply entered the value representing EOF). So you're trying to write the value `input` to an infinite progression higher and higher in the `inputNumber` array, way out of bounds of the array.

Perhaps you want to move scanf inside of the loop?

Edit: Also, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, if you're trying to read in a number character by character ("digit by digit") and store it in the array, you could do that with the [getchar](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htmhttp://) function, which would return buffered input (i.e., standard input after you press enter) character by character as a `char` data type. In which case your `inputNumber` array would have to be a char array, and you would have to parse it into an integer with some code. Again, not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but I figured I'd mention it.